# crash when I click a button

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a button to get to a new Activity, but the app crash when I click on it. what can I do to fix this? This is the code I just for opening the Activity

```
public class Programvare extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_programvare);

        Button home = (Button)findViewById(R.id.home);
        home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent startIntent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                // Show how to pass Information to another Activity
                startActivity(startIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: add error log please.

Comment: with error loag also show your mainfest file

Comment: show your error log

Answer (score 1):

You already place on an Activity. So no need to get context from `getApplicationContext()`. Use this instead of `getApplicationContext()`.

```
Intent startIntent = new Intent (Programvare.this, MainActivity.class);
// Show how to pass Information to another Activity
startActivity(startIntent);
```

And also check `AndroidManifest.xml`. Is MainActivity is added or not. If not please add MainActivity in the activity list like this.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: How is `this` going to work inside `Anonymous Class`?

Comment: Oops! Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Xml define

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/my_button"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

In Activity

```
 Button myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent startIntent = new Intent (Programvare.this, MainActivity.class);
            // Show how to pass Information to another Activity
            startActivity(startIntent);
        }
    });
```

Instead of 'home' use other ids.

Hope it may help you

Answer (score 0):

change your code for going in second activity :

```
Intent startIntent = new Intent (Programvare.this, MainActivity.class);
// Show how to pass Information to another Activity
startActivity(startIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
  Intent startIntent = new Intent (Programvare.this, MainActivity.class);
  startActivity(startIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

check the `AndroidManifest.xml` it should include all the project activities.

Hope it may help.